# Tor connection in guest OS is being blocked by unknown firewall At Host OS

Tags: firewall, blocked

I am having a problem setting up tor through virtual box and let me give you guys some details:
I have installed tor bundle on win xp that is installed on virtual box but when i am trying to activate tor bundle it won't connect, it will get stuck in the "loading network status" level.
I have malware anti bytes installed on the pc and norton anti virus.
malware antybytes will show me message when i am trying to connect to tor like :"website blocked ip:61231 port" i will get a few messages like this and it just won't connect to tor on guest os.
i tried to deactivate norton and malware antybytes but it still won't connect to tor.
What else shall i try?

Comment: Uninstalling them etirely? Setting an exception for the VirtualBox process?

Answer (score 1):

Malwarebytes is blocking Tor - it's a known issue. If I got you right - you have two antiviruses on one PC, it's a bad idea nowdays: I remember 1994 - yes, then  it made some sense, but not now. Some network filtering is remaining when the AV is deactivated, and - if your host is also Windows - it can activate windows defender+firewall when disabling other antivirus... Use network bridge for your virtual machine - it should keep you out of trouble. And feel free to ask further if it will not work - together we will solve this, don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to ping your gateway (router IP) and public DNS (8.8.8.8) from your virtual box? This will prove if you have internet connectivity on your VM. In bridge mode, your NIC will directly connect to your WiFi meaning you've to ensure you've not enabled MAC filtering (add vm's mac if you've enabled) and also you must add credentials to attach the VM  onto wifi.